# Datepicker with jquery with month and years as grid

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins

I am looking to use jquery/jquery UI to build a datepicker, where I can click on the month name in the title in the calendar view and see a grid of month names with a year name in the title, and so on (similar to Windows 7 calendar).

Is there anyway I can use the datepicker UI for this. (With datepicker, I can get a basic date picker with a default calendar view.) Any way it can be modified to add a grid of months and a grid of years to be selected from?

Comment: I have been using a jquery plugin http://xdsoft.net/jqplugins/datetimepicker/ and I am pleased with it. Check it out.

Answer (score 1):

I have seen something like that in a plugin called Datepair.js

http://jonthornton.github.io/Datepair.js/